# Break out of while loop handling keybreak exception correctly

Tags: python, loops, exception, atomic

I need to implement a function which monitors the status of a running job until it is completed. Something like this:

```py
def monitor_job(job_id):
    ended = False
    while not ended:
        ended = check_if_ended(job_id)
        time.sleep(5)

    print('ended')
```

Now I want to allow a user to break the loop using Ctrl-C, and in that case I want to stop the job gracefully calling a `stop_job()` function. However this function is asyncronous, it just submits a request to stop the job, which can take some time to complete. Therefore after this call I would like to continue the while loop and wait for the job to end. Here is an attempt:

```py
def monitor_job(job_id):
    keybreaks = False
    ended = False
    while not ended:

        # (...)

        try:
            ended = check_if_ended(job_id)
            time.sleep(5)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            # break after a second keybreak
            if keybreaks:
                raise
            keybreaks = True
            stop_job(job_id)

    print('ended')
```

What I don't like in this solution is that if, by chance, Ctrl-C is triggered outside of the `try` (for example at the `(...)`) then the exception would not be catched, and the job would not be stopped gracefully.

**Is there a good way to handle this correctly, avoiding such kind of timing problem?**

I have thought of some solution like: replicating the while loop inside the `except` block, which isn't elegant; or putting the `try` outside of the `while` loop and then calling back `monitor_job()` in the `except`, but then the Ctrl-C might happen during the function call.

Comment: If you don't put any code outside the `try` (where `(...)` is)  then it should always be catched. So just move everything inbetween the `while` and the `try` statement into the `try` block.

Comment: You mean it is very unlikely to happen or it is impossible to happen? I want to make it impossible in principle

Comment: It is "only" very unlikely, but bordering impossible. Because you sleep is so long in comparison to everything else it is very very unlikely that the `sigint` will hit outside the try block. For "impossible in principle" see my answer below. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible that the `Ctrl-C` happens at the `(...)`. But it is only a **very!** small chance.

If you want to be absolutely certain you could use the following snippet:

```
def monitor_job(job_id, first_call=True):
    ended = False
    try:
        if first_call:
            monitor_job(job_id, first_call=False)
        while not ended:
            ended = check_if_ended(job_id)
            time.sleep(5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if first_call:
            raise
```

It also uses a recursion like you proposed but not in the except block but in the try block. So when you hit `Ctrl-C` you first exit the inner call to `monitor_job(first_call=False)` and only after the second `Ctrl-C` do you exit the outer function.

That is the most elegant solution I was able to come up with.